# Vue js getting Information from HTML input field and creating new table with this data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hey my technically enthusiastic friends!

I don't know where to start - I've spent hours on it and I can't find a solution. I want a simple HTML table, where elements can be added dynamically, and I want to do this via Vue js. The whole thing should be done with simple input fields and an add button, but I don't know how to read in the data. I know a little bit about vue js by now, but I don't quite get it. It's not much code, so I would be happy if someone can help me with an example in this direction. Just a table to which you can add data that was previously entered via input fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please refer to the classic to-do list example in Vue.js. Meanwhile, how can you tell that "it is not much code" if you are new to Vue.js? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is you need to create is a form and a table to display it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   user: {
     name: '',
     age: ''
    },
    users: [],
  },
  methods: {
   submitForm: function(){
     users.push(user)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <span>Name</span>
      <input type="text" v-model="user.name">
      <span>age</span>
      <input type="text" v-model="user.age">
      <input type="submit" onClick=onSubmit() />
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <table>
    <tr v-for="user in users">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Exactly what i was looking for! I had several examples but none of these were just as simple to understand as this. I think i got it now. helped me a lot!